# MSSQL Returns Different result in SSMS and Node JS script

Tags: sql, node.js, sql-server, ssms

I have a SQL query to return customer's transaction header using customer's `card_number`. The SQL query will return a column called `audit_number`. The problem is the when i execute the SQL query using SSMS software, the query returns proper results, but when i execute the query on my Node JS script some of the `audit_number` are wrong.

[image: audit_number]

The `audit_number` should be **14111990000015953** and **14111990000015952** but when i execute the query in my NODE JS script both `audit_number` become **14111990000015952**.

[image: audit_number_2]

Here is my sql query

```
SELECT
h.Log_trxdate AS trx_date, 
CAST(h.log_audit AS varchar) AS audit_number,  
h.currency_code  
FROM log_header h  
WHERE h.id_code = '10000010055919' --card_number
```

Here is my Node JS Script

```
var querySQL = " SELECT  ";
querySQL = querySQL + " h.Log_trxdate AS trx_date, ";
querySQL = querySQL + " CAST(h.log_audit AS varchar) AS audit_number, ";
querySQL = querySQL + " FROM log_header h ";
querySQL = querySQL + " WHERE h.id_code = 10000010055919 ";

sql.connect(config, function (err) {
    var req = new sql.Request();
    req.query(querySQL, function (err, result) {
    console.log(result);        
    });
});
```

Comment: What data type is _log_audit_ in the database?

Comment: and also.... never use `varchar`, always use a size.... something like `varchar(20)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your datatype `number` to `varchar/text` since in `javascript` if the number length is more than 16 digits then it will give you some random number.

> So to get exact result you should change your Datatype from number to string.

```
For example if you check number
Number(1111111111111111)//16 digits

Result is 1111111111111111

But if you put Number(11111111111111111)//17 digits
then result will be 11111111111111112 something
```

Comment: Can you post some javascript code that reproduces this?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid you can just check it in chrome dev tool console. put Number(1111111111111111) and Number(11111111111111111)

Comment: Wow that's interesting. So it overflows and just gives you the wrong number?

Comment: JavaScript is so fantastic yet so riddled with wierd things like this

Comment: All languages have pros and cons :)

Comment: Javascript was basically designed to "keep running no matter what fails".

Comment: Thank you Mr. abdulbarik. Solved by `CAST`ing the `card_number` into varchar